# Removing Noetherian hypotheses

Tags: algebraic-geometry

The following proposition is proved in EGA. Since EGA is somewhat intimidating(and it is written in French), I'm looking for a more readable proof.

**EGA IV-3 (8.9.1) (ii)**
Let $A$ be a ring.
Let $X$ be a scheme which is quasi-compact, quasi-separated and locally of finite presentation over $A$.
Let $\mathcal{F}$ be an $\mathcal{O}_X$-module of finite presentation.
Then there exist a subring $A_0$ of $A$, which is of finite type over $\mathbb{Z}$ and a scheme $X_0$ of finite type over $A_0$ and a coherent $\mathcal{O}_{X_0}$-module $\mathcal{F}_0$ such that $X = X_0\times _{A_0} A$ and $\mathcal{F} = \mathcal{F}_0\otimes_{A_0} A$.
Moreover $Supp(\mathcal{F})$ is constructible and closed, and there exists a closed subscheme $Z$ of $X$ such that $|Z| = Supp(\mathcal{F})$ and the canonical morphism $Z \rightarrow X$ is locally of finite presentation.